# How do i get a value from a key in the first element in a list with dictionaries python?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I`ve created a generator which creates a list with dicts {customer: "customer", key_id: key_id, key: "key"}

I need to retrieve assign each key to a variable in my models.py to send it to my database sqlite via sqlalchemy.

I am really new at this and after googling for hours i`m giving up..
Since it is in a for loop my brain is telling me that i can extract a new line for each loop.
Like you see in my code, last thing I tried was to convert mye dictlist to a dict..

```
data_generert = keydata.generator(amount, customer) 
#outputs a dictlist
#{'customer': 'hoppsann', 'key_id': 1, 'key': 'PsqnF6TBVQ'}
#{'customer': 'hoppsann', 'key_id': 2, 'key': '8ZE174eH5t'}
#{'customer': 'hoppsann', 'key_id': 3, 'key': 'g1gKESViEB'}
#{'customer': 'hoppsann', 'key_id': 4, 'key': 'd45Tbvq3mu'}
#{'customer': 'hoppsann', 'key_id': 5, 'key': 'lySs6q2ekG'}
#{'customer': 'hoppsann', 'key_id': 6, 'key': 'XKnup84vxv'}

   
    for i in data_generert:
        keys = Keys() # This is my model for sqalchemy
        data_generert = {}
        keys.customer = data_generert["customer"]
        keys.key = data_generert["key"]
        keys.key_id = data_generert["key_id"]

        db.add(keys)
        db.commit()
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, your generator yields a `dict` each iteration. Then that would mean that `for i in data_generert` each `i` would be a `dict`. So you should access values via `i` (`i["customer"]`, `i["Key"]`, `i["key_id"]`)

Comment: Why are you resetting `data_generert` to an empty dict in Line 2 of your for loop?

Comment: @MattDMo that was a part of the "I`m really new to this" and tried something. It was the last thing i tried to convert the "i" to a dict..

Comment: @HenryEcker: That was to simple... THANK YOU!

Comment: @HenryEcker Could you please submit it as an answer? That way I can accept it and close the question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, your generator yields a `dict` each iteration. Then that would mean that for `i` in `data_generert` each `i` would be a `dict`.

So you should access values via `i`.

I recommend changing the variable name to something more understandable to make it clear that each value is a `dict` and not the standard `int` iterator value that `i` typically represents.

```py
data_generert = keydata.generator(amount, customer)

for d in data_generert:
    keys = Keys()
    keys.customer = d["customer"]
    keys.key = d["key"]
    keys.key_id = d["key_id"]

    db.add(keys)
    db.commit()
```